# Is there a program like Fedy but for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation

Fedy is a program that has tweaks and programs that are otherwise proprietary, and you can install them with one click.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like the Software-Boutique, comes default with Ubuntu-MATE, but can be installed & run from any *Ubuntu.  If the selected software requires a PPA be added, the Boutique adds it for you.  (https://snapcraft.io/software-boutique though I've only used the non-snap version)  It doesn't list every piece of software, trying to limit itself to the 'best' (or top-of-class) for each category.

Comment: The ubuntu-restricted-extras duplicate link answers the first screenshot but it doesn't answer the other two screenshots.

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/software/fedy/ shows none

Answer (score 5):

Try the Software-Boutique, which comes default with Ubuntu-MATE, but can be installed & run from any *Ubuntu. 
[image]
If the selected software requires a PPA be added, the Boutique adds it for you.

https://snapcraft.io/software-boutique

It doesn't list every piece of software, trying to limit itself to the 'best' (or top-of-class) for each category.

---

To install (snap) on my 18.04 laptop, I needed to use

```
sudo snap install ubuntu-mate-welcome --classic
sudo snap install software-boutique  --classic
```

and it was run with `ubuntu-mate-welcome --boutique`

*but I suggest giving the snap version a miss if using a limited resource machine, it was painful on this dual core machine with only 2gb ram, I've had no issues using non-snap version*

Comment: Please note:  As of 19.10 there are issues with running Software Boutique on other flavors of Ubuntu. It comes only as a *classic* snap, and b/c there are problems with detecting dependencies in *classic* snaps, the fix currently is to refuse to run in other flavors.   Please refer to https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-19-10-software-boutique-fail-to-run/20453/2  (*which has two work-arounds though possibly not ideal*).

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mate-dev/+archive/ubuntu/welcome provides easiest access to software boutique up to current *hirsute* (tested with Lubuntu); I stopped using the *snap* version some time ago