# Ubuntu-software center only shows featured and editors' picks

Tags: software-center

I see that more people have asked this question without reply.

I have tried to reinstall the software-center, but without luck. anybody ever managed to fix this problem? i really like browsing for software..

this is how it looks:

[image: this is how it looks]

it is something that's been around now for some months..

thanks in advance :*

Comment: Sorry I can't offer any advice on the issue  (I use `aptitude` (text) or only very rarely `synaptic`),  but would like to suggest you try the Software-Boutique which comes with Ubuntu-MATE.  For a GUI tool, i've been very impressed (*even though I don't use it*)  It doesn't list everything, but tries to list the 'best-of-class' (with exceptions for 'taste' eg. browsers).   I'll refer you to a question where I suggested it as an answer (if you have more questions; please just ask me).  ps: it works on any *Ubuntu; not just MATE..

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058304/is-there-a-program-like-fedy-but-for-ubuntu/1058306#1058306  (sorry I forgot to paste the link I was referring to...)

Comment: good suggestion, and i installed it with snap, but it doesn't show up anywhere.. and when i type it in terminal to start it.. it just says it is in development.. any idea?

Comment: and synaptic really confuses me

Comment: thanks for comment (re: software-boutique), this machine didn't have it installed so I installed; realized your issue and have no added more instruction in the answer where I used software-boutique (ie. commands needed to install, plus run the snap version)

Comment: The answer may have something to do with the fact that neither editors picks nor featured are dynamically displayed. I noticed that mine started crapping out at the same time as my connection. It's far from an answer, but at least it's a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** 19/8/2018 
as mentioned by @geras, an official fix for unescape metadata on `fwupd.xml` has been committed to ubuntu xenial -proposed repository (see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream-glib/+bug/1780442)). It permanently fixes the issue even though the `fwupdmgr` refreshes. To do that you can first go to **Software & Updates** > **Developer Options** > check the **Pre-release updates**. Then, `sudo apt update && sudo apt install fwupd/xenial-proposed`. After that reboot the PC.

Are you experiencing these errors when updating your ubuntu using `sudo apt update`:

```
AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: Metadata files have errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/cache/app-info -a -e /usr/bin/appstreamcli; then appstreamcli refresh-cache > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

If so, you can try the solutions provided on this link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream/+bug/1644498

1) Open `fwupd.xml` file

```
sudo gedit /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
```

2) Edit line #265

```
<checksum filename="Firmware_SF30&SN30_Pro_V1.26.dat"
```

becomes

```
<checksum filename="Firmware_SF30&amp;SN30_Pro_V1.26.dat"
```

(change `&` with `&amp;`)

3) Refresh the `appstreamcli`

```
sudo appstreamcli refresh --force
```

These tricks are worked for me to solve the Ubuntu Software problem.

Comment: No.. apt is working perfectly.. i tried it anyway.. nothing changed.. also, the line number was 265.. not 256. . but thanks though :)

Comment: @zuv I did have exactly the errors that you described and your solution worked for me but only temporarily. After some time the file reverts to the '&'-containing version. However, maybe it will be enough to wait for a fix to this bug to be released: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/appstream-glib/+bug/1780442

Comment: @BanjooMørmaid, I see. Sorry I cannot provide you another solution since I solved this problem with this trick. :( Also, for the line number, it's my mistake. It should be 265. :)

Comment: @geras, thank you for sharing that link. I have checked and confirmed that the fix is worked for me. I think that will be the official fix for ubuntu (xenial).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesnt work for me

Comment: @zuv,  it's my bad, your solution help me indeed and ubuntu software go smoothly now

Answer (score 0):

I installed Gnome Software.  It works while Ubuntu software doesn't fully work, at least for exploring for apps.  I pinned it to the favorites bar.  It is available on the Ubuntu Software app, I believe.