# Ubuntu 20.10 - Ubuntu Software not populating or showing applications

Tags: updates, software-center, 20.10

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.10 with all packages updated. I open Ubuntu Software and it only shows the "Editors Picks" but if I click any of the categories no programs will load in the next window. I can search for applications just fine though.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This also happened with me on a fresh ubuntu install. I however, reinstalled to fix this and a few other bugs. But this should fix it:
sudo apt update && sudo apt install fwupd/xenial-proposed
i tried this answer and it worked !
[i attached the link to a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059968/ubuntu-software-center-only-shows-featured-and-editors-picks)

Comment: oh sorry if u think my answer is a bit unproper. these are my first times on online forums and i didnt  knew how to attach a link :)

Comment: hmm wasn't really able to come up with a solution with that.

Comment: then switch to synaptic (alternate for software center) , it is far better than sluggish flatpak and other packages. Do sudo apt install synaptic