# how to install software without using ubuntu software

Tags: 16.04

I have a new 16.04 install and ubuntu software is not working.
how to install software without using ubuntu software? is there a way to see a list of software available?

Comment: My favorite would be `aptitude` (text only, but few would probably agree), far more popular though is `synaptic`, but one I often recommend is `software boutique` (a link to where I've recommended it is https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058304/is-there-a-program-like-fedy-but-for-ubuntu/1058306#1058306). It lists only what it calls 'top of class' (except for things like browsers where is provide lots of choice as it's personal), plus if it lists things outside of repos (eg. skype etc) adding the ppa required if you choose you need such software.