# No Gui, just black screen

Tags: lubuntu

I recently installed Lubuntu 18.10

The other night, while looking at my display settings, I could see something about X render, and GLX (OpenGL). For some reason I decided to click on the GLX option.

Right away my screen was corrupted and I was unable to click on anything. 
So I launched the terminal and typed  reboot or sudo reboot  actually. 
I was able to get back into the Gui, but when I went to check my display properties again   the screen again went silly on me,  splitting the display in half and not letting me click on anything. All I could do was launch a terminal, ctrl alt t,  and once again choose to reboot.

Now lubuntu starts to load up, but once the  splash screen with the progress dots goes away, I'm left at a black screen, my cursor, and nothing else. Won't launch the Gui.

What can I do to set things straight again.?  Thanks in advance..

Comment: I'm somewhat confused; you start talking about Ubuntu, then switch to Lubuntu before tagging Xubuntu. The X11/GL question is key, but I can't imagine what question you're talking about & mentioning three different desktops/flavors doesn't help.

Comment: I downloaded what I think was referred to as lubuntu 18.10
My question iis... How can I get back to a Gui desktop. 
I selected GL as a renderer (X something  was selexted)
And then my screen went bad, splitting in half, not showing wallpaper or a dock, or letting me click on anything, except to launch a terminal via ctrl alt t
From there, I did a sudo reboot,  and the machine rebooted. 
However, after the loading splash screen with the progress indicator dots goes away, rather than put me at a Gui desktop, it just sits at a black screen. 
Thanks

Comment: When stuck at the black screen, I can anger, uname - a, and this is what I get...  Linux 4.18.0-generic #17- Ubuntu smp Fri Feb 8... etc

Comment: Are you using Lubuntu 18.10? (thus LXQt)  or Xubuntu 18.10? (thus XFCE) or Ubuntu 18.10? (thus GNOME)  So far your question is just unclear, and we cannot help you much as we don't even know what you are running.  *If you have additional information (or wish to clear up your question), please edit the question & add there*

Comment: Lubuntu 18.10   and  I beleive it is LXQt

Comment: I booted two systems (Lubuntu 19.04) & looked but cannot find what you may have changed. The best I can suggest is to look in your `history` (if you used commands to change settings but I'm betting no), or in ~/.config/lxqt  (eg. `ls -ltrh $HOME/.config/lxqt`) and look for a file dated around the time you made a change & explore there.   You still have Xubuntu tagged in your question, and this advice is Lubuntu (18.10 & later) only.

Comment: Preferences>lxqt settings>window effects >'other' tab. Shows X render & GLX.   For some reason I clicked on GLX, exited, and all went wrong and cannot get back to a gui.   Hope this helps. Might just reinstall or go for the Ubuntu iso instead? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. Did not select Xubuntu as a tag. I'm new and don't know what I'm doing I guess. But I think I just changed the tsg. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, looking at a file named, lxqt-config-appearance.conf      it says the following... Controlgtkthemeenabled=true.  Also says, _userfile_=true.   Perhaps I can edit this file to put me back to the X Render? Maybe that'll fix things up? Doing this off the live USB I made to install this in the first place.   Appreciate the help, sorry for confusion.

Comment: I've never touched that option, and don't see any reference to it in official docs (https://manual.lubuntu.me/3/3.2/3.2.16/window_effects.html).  I was exploring setting up a test-environment so I could test for you (ideally not risk my used systems) but I'd suggest first making the line a comment (I'm not familiar with openbox configs, either # or ! as first character I believe will make the line a comment).  That would be my approach, something that is easy to reverse if it doesn't help.  I find no refernece to 'gtx' in my config files, which is why I'd comment out instead of =false

Comment: Hmm, ok. So just put a # in front of that line...can try that.  I know why I clicked on the GLX option, I was trying to get shadows and transparency to work.

Comment: Playing with the live desktop (off the USB), I did not select GLX this time, but selected 'Compton' from menu> Accessories >Compton.   This gave me shadows and transparency to the windows only, not the panel. But, display is all messed up. So I dunno.  What r u running? And does it all work right out of the box?  Because I find that the Discover software center runs slow as molasses. Realy realy sloooow.  Thanks

Comment: This isn't a discussion site - I'd suggest irc for that.  The box I've replied here from is 10 years old & I'm happy, but I wouldn't use compton (heavy on cpu just for eye-candy; no thanks).  I didn't see any difference when I selected GLX(OpenGL) & learnt nothing more. On logout & login again I saw no difference but my gpu is most likely different to yours, and I used 19.04.  I use `aptitude` or cli rather to grab software rather than discover/muon  (though I do like Software-Boutique for non-repo titles https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058304/is-there-a-program-like-fedy-but-for-ubuntu)

Comment: Alright, running off the USB, I tried enabling COMPTON again, and this time it created shadows and transparency on windows, and after unchecking 'Avoid drawing shadows on dock/panel windows', it gave me shadows on the panel now.  About to try and reboot into the installed version to see if that changes file did anything good.  I take it that running live off the USB, does not save your settings?? Doesn't seem to for me. Brb after reboot.

Comment: 'live' mode lets you boot & run everything from memory (loaded from compressed images on your thumb-drive/dvdr/media).  It lets you mount & make changes to hdd/ssd if made to those files (wherever you mounted it), but no everything saved to the '/' or 'live' file-system is only in memory & lost on reboot.

Comment: Okay, looks like you can get the live running to save settings... Something to do with persistence, and it looked a little overwhelming. So I think I'll just try a reinstall of lububtu, as the change to that config file did nothing to solve my problem, unfortunately. If I can't get things to behave the way I would like, in this version, perhaps I'll try my luck with Mint, mate version. Thank you for your help. Sorry it didn't work.  Now, if there is a cure for that extremely slow DISCOVER pkg center, that would be great. It all but freezes up my system. Perhaps a different package manager?

Comment: Hi guiverc, you said...I use aptitude or cli rather to grab software rather than discover/muon (though I do like Software-Boutique for non-repo titles.
Thanks, Going to look into Synaptic as well. Discover just plain sucks unfortunately, as its the mngr that is preinstalled with this distro.  Muon seems to work fine tho. so I have some options.