# How can I install Telegram app in 18.04?

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, xubuntu

When I try to install Telegram, I get the following error:

```
itsmarttricks@mangesh:~$ sudo apt-get install telegram
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:6.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-report-builder : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-script-provider-bsh : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-script-provider-js : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-script-provider-python : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-colibre : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-elementary : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
 libreoffice-style-tango : Depends: libreoffice-common (= 1:6.2.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your issue, but for common programs that are outside of default repositories, a simple way is via the Ubuntu-MATE Software Boutique (refer to my answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058304/is-there-a-program-like-fedy-but-for-ubuntu for how). It can be used on any Ubuntu flavor (not just mate).

Comment: @ShadowWizard this type of complaint is better used in **custom flags instead of public comments**.  Please flag cases such as this accordingly, rather than posting comments here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got LibreOffice installed, but somehow managed to break its installation. To fix it, try:

```
sudo apt-mark auto libreoffice-common
```

If you've got an old version of `apt-get` (before 11.something, I think – well before Ubuntu 18.04's version) and this doesn't work, try instead:

```
sudo apt-get markauto libreoffice-common
```

and then update your package manager immediately.

After running one of these commands, run:

```
sudo apt install
```

(I think.)