# gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/user/.gnupg'

Tags: apt, permissions, gnome-terminal, gnupg, tor

I am trying to install Tor Browser following this guide:

https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en on Ubuntu 18.04.3 TLS.

When running the following command:

```
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | apt-key add -
```

I get the error message below:

```
E: This command can only be used by root.
```

When I run the same command using `sudo`, I get the following message:

```
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/user/.gnupg'
E: This command can only be used by root.
```

Does anyone know how to fix it and why it is happening?

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at the Software Boutique - refer to this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058304/is-there-a-program-like-fedy-but-for-ubuntu/1058306#1058306  It's a gui that adds the required sources automatically when you select packages that need different sources msking common programs like tor-browser super easy to install.

Comment: Your first line consists of two commands, `gpg` which is then piped to your `apt-key` so when you mention `sudo` I wonder if how you used it as you were unclear. More so though, I wonder what is the owner of ~/.gnupg  (whether in prior `sudo` commands you've changed ownership to root instead of your user id) thus your permissions error..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How exactly did you try to use it with `sudo`?

My guess is:

```
sudo gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | apt-key add -
```

If so, `gpg` will run as root, and `apt-key` will run as your normal user.

In this particular case you should add `sudo` infront of `apt-key`:

```
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Since you ran `gpg` with `sudo` and not using the `-H` flag the permissions on `~/.gnupg` probably changed.

From [`man sudo`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo):

> -H' The -H (HOME) option requests that the security policy set the HOME environment variable to the home directory of the target user
>   (root by default) as specified by the password database. Depending on
>   the policy, this may be the default behavior.

To check permissions and ownership:

```
ls -l ~/.gnupg
```

If the directory (`.`) or any files in the directory is owned by `root`, fix the permissions with:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.gnupg
sudo find ~/.gnupg -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
sudo find ~/.gnupg -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
```

Comment: When I did sudo in front of apt-key ... i got:

gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/user/.gnupg'
OK

Comment: @mgor My `~/.gnupg` has a sub-directory named `private-keys-v1.d`.  After your `chmod 600 ~/.gnupg/*` that directory will be `drw-` instead of `drwx`.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: @JonBrave updated the chmod commands to take this into consideration, thanks.