# Looking for a stable KDE environment

Tags: virtualbox, kde

Can someone suggest a stable KDE distro for a more-less newbie user (a few month old in terms of Linux usage)?

I've already tried Manjaro, Neon, Chakra, and currently installing Kubuntu on my virtualbox (cannot do it live, since it's a working laptop, and I need stability there). All of the upper had issues in different fields -

Manjaro crashed the whole thing when it came to VPN connecting - the spinning network icon generally deadlocked the thread, which was responsible for UI drawing, making all calls to it, like "Context menu" and even autohide elements, simply not draw until the VPN got connected.

Chakra - saw that it's latest build was 2017, so skipped it

Neon. Just now updated it and all of the windows started to draw two pairs of control buttons (save, cancel and etc), drawing the second one upside down, on the top of the screen (thank you, but no thank you).

And currently I'm installing Kubuntu to see how it goes.

I generally need something stable, and with a repo, on which I could install without High Grade linux stuff, things like skype (and Intellj Idea).

Comment: In general Ubuntu LTS is considered stable (currently that is Kubuntu 18.04). If you are done installing Kubuntu and have problems with it, you may ask specific questions here. This general stability question is too broad and not answerable imo. Questions to other distros are off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks. I am currently using Ubuntu 18 with Gnome, but the list of small issues are driving me in the direction of reconsider. Thing it will be the best option to post the issues, I am facing with Gnome, and not go the other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubuntu is the only stable KDE distribution on-topic for this site.

https://kubuntu.org/

The most stable is of course the LTS or long-term-support release, the latest being 18.04 LTS (ie. from 2018-April).

The latest release at the time of writing this answer is 19.04 with 19.10 just a few days away. Releases that aren't designated LTS have support for only nine months as opposed to Kubuntu 18.04 LTS which is supported for three years.

It can be downloaded from https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/

*If you want to download a flavor and aren't sure what address to go to, please search for it on ubuntu.com.  A number of 'fan' sites that have nothing to do with official flavor teams or with Ubuntu provide downloads that may or may not be legitimate, and Google tends to rank such sites highly.  Legitimate download links are available at https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours*.

Comment: If you can't find additional popular software with default repos, my fall-back place is the Software Boutique (*from Ubuntu-MATE, but it'll work in any Ubuntu*).  It'll add official or checked PPA's if required or not available as snaps.

Comment: Please mention the package name for the Software Boutique to use with `sudo apt install …`.

Comment: https://snapcraft.io/software-boutique     For help installing please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058304/is-there-a-program-like-fedy-but-for-ubuntu

Comment: I edited your answer a bit. Please check if the changes are okay. Thanks!