# Any good alternative for PicPick?

Tags: photo-editing

I just moved to Ubuntu from the Windows world and I feel so refreshed here.
I'm looking for a good alternative for PicPick https://picpick.app/en/
Please suggest some.

Comment: Start with your Ubuntu Software application. Use it's Search feature. Try a a few applications. You won't many find all-in-one bundles. Windows applications and Ubuntu software do not map exactly one-to-one, and software is often built around workflows.

Comment: You haven't mentioned your release, but I've always liked the *Software Boutique* (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058304/is-there-a-program-like-fedy-but-for-ubuntu)  which tries to provide the *best in class* for most classes of software. Whilst it's *curated list* won't match everyone's tastes, I've often found it a good starting point (moving to package managers if I want something else)...  Software Boutique is easily installed on some releases (if not using Ubuntu-MATE), not so much later release (*but you didn't give any specifics*)

Comment: I'm a big fan of [this site](https://alternativeto.net/software/picpick/?platform=linux). In fact, I'm also going to ping @guiverc in the off chance that he's not already familiar with said site. The list of alternatives on said site is vast and well categorized/indexed. It's almost as user-friendly as it can be, but not quite.